# Flexible pane exceed 100% height

Tags: css, reactjs

It's basically **CSS question**, but since it's wrapped inside React, I tagged it as React as well.

Demo to my problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bartik-z9lev
(Those who don't know React, just watch the live demo and use for example Google Chrome's F12 panel to see the elements and styles)

So basically I have two main sections in my app, the `top` one and `bottom` one, and a flexible divider that you can resize them.

My goal is to eventually make my `bottom` section to a chat, so I made it's `overflow: scroll`.

***But the weird situation is***: when I resize it towards down, the bottom section height become larger than the screen, which cause the overflow to not be true.

An image example ( watch the bottom part ):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3WDJ.png

So basically I want the bottom's height to always be 100% relative to the top part and the whole screen, and if there is more text than it could hold, so the `overflow: scroll` will be activated.

I tried ( once again, via F12 ) to change the style of many elements there so it will work fine, but I couldn't achieve that goal.

Without the live demo:

**Full Code**:

`App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import SplitPane from "react-split-pane";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SplitPane split="horizontal">
      <div>test</div>
      <div style={{ overflow: "scroll" }}>
        <LongText />
      </div>
    </SplitPane>
  );
}
```

`styles.css` ( for the divider ):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.Resizer {
  background: rgb(66, 66, 66);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.Resizer.vertical::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 11px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute !important;
}

.Resizer.horizontal::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  height: 11px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute !important;
}

.Resizer:hover {
  background: rgb(224, 224, 224);
}

.Resizer.horizontal {
  height: 1px;
  cursor: row-resize;
  width: 100%;
}

.Resizer.horizontal:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.Resizer.vertical {
  width: 1px;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.Resizer.vertical:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.Resizer.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.Resizer.disabled:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

Explanation ( about `App.js` ):

The first child: `<div>Top</div>` is the top one, and the second `<div>` is the bottom part ( which the long text inside )

There is also CSS file in the `codesandbox` demo link I sent, that handles the divider style.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D Changed my question to include the full code ( kept the live demo but it nows should be understandable without it as well ).